# error qreating qci plugin for QT, mingw32-make error

Tags: oracle, qt, mingw32

i'm trying to create QCI plugin so i can connect my ORACLE db but fails...
following those stages:

```
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;c:\oracle\oci\include
set LIB=%LIB%;c:\oracle\oci\lib\msvc
cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\oci
qmake -o Makefile oci.pro
mingw32-make
```

i get this error:

```
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIResult[vtable
 for QOCIResult]+0x54): undefined reference to `QSqlCachedResult::fetchPrevious()'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIResult[vtable
 for QOCIResult]+0x58): undefined reference to `QSqlCachedResult::fetchFirst()'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIResult[vtable
 for QOCIResult]+0x5c): undefined reference to `QSqlCachedResult::fetchLast()'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.o: In function `ZN10QOCIDriver11qt_metacastEPKc':
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:59: undefined reference to `QSqlDriver::qt_metacast(char
 const*)'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.o: In function `ZN10QOCIDriver11qt_metacallEN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv':
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:64: undefined reference to `QSqlDriver::qt_metacall(QMet
aObject::Call, int, void**)'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.o: In function `Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii':
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:43: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10QSqlDriver16stati
cMetaObjectE'
tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.o: In function `ZSt3minIjERKT_S2_S2_':
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.text$_ZNK14QScopedPointerI11QObjectData21QScopedPointe
rDeleterIS0_EEptEv[QScopedPointer<QObjectData, QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >::operator->() const]+0x26): undefined reference to `_imp
___Z9qt_assertPKcS0_i'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x1c): u
ndefined reference to `QObject::event(QEvent*)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x20): u
ndefined reference to `QObject::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x24): u
ndefined reference to `QObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x28): u
ndefined reference to `QObject::childEvent(QChildEvent*)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x2c): u
ndefined reference to `QObject::customEvent(QEvent*)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x30): u
ndefined reference to `QObject::connectNotify(char const*)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x34): u
ndefined reference to `QObject::disconnectNotify(char const*)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDrivCreating library file: c:\Qt\2010.
02.1\qt\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlocid4.a
er[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x38): undefined reference to `QSqlDriver::isOpen() const'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x5c): u
ndefined reference to `QSqlDriver::sqlStatement(QSqlDriver::StatementType, QString const&, QSqlRecord const&, bool) const'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x74): u
ndefined reference to `QSqlDriver::setOpen(bool)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x78): u
ndefined reference to `QSqlDriver::setOpenError(bool)'
C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_qsql_oci.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10QOCIDriver[vtable for QOCIDriver]+0x7c): u
ndefined reference to `QSqlDriver::setLastError(QSqlError const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlocid4.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci'
mingw32-make: *** [debug-all] Error 2
```

please help... 
as i can see in the net no replies regarding for QCI problems and i doubt it's even possible....

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `sql` listed in your `.pro` file something like this?

```
QT = core gui sql
```